# Present Apple Sign In view in a landscape orientation?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

The view of Apple Sign In, presented by ASAuthorizationController, shows only in portrait mode, but I would prefer to show it in landscape mode like my app.

Code:

```
    let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
    let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
```

Comment: I don't believe that there is an option for landscape presentation as sign in with Apple can use Face ID and Face ID only works in portrait mode on iPhones; The user would have to rotate their device for the Face ID authentication, but if the dialog was presented in landscape mode this would not be obvious and the user would have a poor experience as Face ID would not work.